# Authenticate user by rank obtained from a mysql database without using mysql query

Tags: c#, mysql, authentication

I've tried authentication using a Mysql query but because of server's restrictions any external connections are not allowed unless you add manually the exceptions but this would be tedious with alot of users.

Here is what i used at first, when the authentication was successful (the username and password exist) should make a label named "status" text say either connected or not connected:

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
    MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection("Server=SERVER;Database=DB;Uid=USER;Pwd=PWD");
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string LabelText
    {
        get
        {
            return this.status.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            this.status.Text = value;
        }
    }

    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo sInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("http://beatpadpc.com/member.php?action=register");
        Process.Start(sInfo);
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public static string MD5Hash(string text)
    {
        MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

        //compute hash from the bytes of text
        md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text));

        //get hash result after compute it
        byte[] result = md5.Hash;

        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        {
            //change it into 2 hexadecimal digits
            //for each byte
            strBuilder.Append(result[i].ToString("x2"));
        }

        return strBuilder.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connect.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM mybb_users WHERE username = " + textBox1.Text + " AND (password = " + MD5Hash(textBox2.Text) + " AND usergroup = \"3\" OR usergroup = \"4\" OR usergroup = \"6\" OR usergroup = \"8\")");
        MySqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (read.Read())
        {
            status.Text = "Connected";
            MessageBox.Show("Success!");
        }
        else
        {
            status.Text = "Not Connected";
            MessageBox.Show("Error!");
        }
    }

}
```

So is there a way to authenticate a user and either if the credentials are correct and the user is on user group 3,4,6 or 8 make status.Text "Connected" or "Not Connected" but taking in count server's restriction to external mysql connections?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably won't want to do the query in the application, but rather on a server. So for example, send the login details to a server and the server returns whether or not the login is correct. This will prevent people from reverse engineering the program and gaining access to the MySQL database credentials, as well as keeping all connections on localhost.

Comment: The question is rather vague. What are groups 3,4,6,8 that you mention at some point? Either you can connect to your MySQL database or you can't, what sort of restrictions are you referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you create a webservice on your server, and call a function on it with the username and encoded password. So the server makes its own connection and only the server connects to itself on MySQL, check this out:

[Web Service built in C# to retrieve data from mySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362835/web-service-built-in-c-sharp-to-retrieve-data-from-mysql-database)

Comment: Could you please give me an example taking in count my previous code? Thank you very much.

Comment: It could be done like this: http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/02/create-and-deploy-a-webservice-using-c/   Once the webservice is done, it will run on the server machine, receive parameters and give you an xml of the result, you won't need to run the queries on your client again.