# Fetching multiple rows from webservice and display it in android listview

Tags: java, android, sql, web-services

i have this webservice:

```
   [WebMethod]
    public string findUserNameById(int Id)
    {
        return getStudent(Id);

    }

    public String getStudent(int id)
    {

        SqlConnection conn;
        conn = Class1.ConnectionManager.GetConnection();
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand();

        newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        newCmd.CommandText = "select * from dbo.tblUser where Id=" + id + "";
        SqlDataReader sdr = newCmd.ExecuteReader();
        String address = null;
        if (sdr.Read())
        {
            address = sdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
            address += "," + sdr.GetValue(1).ToString();
            address += "," + sdr.GetValue(2).ToString();
        }

        conn.Close();
        return address;


    }
```

which retrieve row values like this: Id, name, grade. and im calling this webservice from android application:

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText editText;
private TextView textView;
private Handler mHandler= new Handler();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
}
public void getName(View v){

    String inputId =editText.getText().toString();
    //String[] params= new String[]{"10.0.2.2",inputId};
    String[] params= new String[]{"192.168.1.17:90",inputId};
    new MyAsyncTask().execute(params);

}

class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

    public String SOAP_ACTION="http://tempuri.org/findUserNameById";
    public String OPERATION_NAME ="findUserNameById";
    public String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE ="http://tempuri.org/";
    public String SOAP_ADDRESS;
    private SoapObject request;
    private HttpTransportSE httpTransport;
    private SoapSerializationEnvelope envelop;
    Object response= null;


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        SOAP_ADDRESS="http://"+params[0]+"/myWebService.asmx";
        request= new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
        PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("Id");
        pi.setValue(Integer.parseInt(params[1]));
        pi.setType(Integer.class);
        request.addProperty(pi);
        pi= new PropertyInfo();

        envelop= new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelop.dotNet=true;
        envelop.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        httpTransport=new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
        try{
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelop);
            response=envelop.getResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            response=e.getMessage();
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.setText(result);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to fetch all of the rows and display it in a list view in the android, how to do it?

the query will be like : select * from dbo.tblUser

what should i change in the webservice? also what should i do in java for android?

Comment: what is problem in your own code?

Comment: @sud my code is fine, but its fetching a single row and display it in textview in android. what i want is to fetch multiple rows and display it in listview in android.

Answer (score 0):

try this code-

```
SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();


yourArray=new String[response.getPropertyCount()];

   for(int i=0;i<response.getPropertyCount();i++){    
       Object property = response.getProperty(i);
       if(property instanceof SoapObject){
           SoapObject final_object = (SoapObject) property;
           yourArray[i] = final_object.getProperty("YOUR_PROPERTY_NAME");
    }
}
```

I would recommend that you declare your MainAsyncTask like this:

`public class MainAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {`
Then modify `doInBackground` to do all the processing that you are now doing in `onPostExecute` (except for the `Toast` part if any) and have it return the `String[]` (or null if there's an error). You can store the result code in an instance variable of `MainAsyncTask` and return null on error. Then `onPostExecute` has access to the same info that it does with your current code. Finally, if there is no error, just call a method in your main activity from `onPostExecute` to do the UI updates, passing it the `String[]` result.

Comment: firstly, what should i change in the webservice code so it will return an array?

Comment: try to declare your array in class MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a Model Class which holds all the Property you need to send back

```
Public class Address{
public int grade;
public String name;
public String grade;
}

Create List<Address> addressList;
```

Iterate through the result set you get from database and in each iteration create a address object and put it in List and return List as response

**Edit**
Android Side reading from list you can refer this link
http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/10/web-service-that-returns-array-of.html

**SERVICE SIDE**

Instead of this Line

```
if (sdr.Read())
        {
            address = sdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
            address += "," + sdr.GetValue(1).ToString();
            address += "," + sdr.GetValue(2).ToString();
        }
```

change it to

```
List<Address> addressList=new ArrayList<Address>();
while (sdr.Read())
        {
           Address address=new Address();
            address.id = sdr.GetValue(0);
            address.name= sdr.GetValue(1).ToString();
            address.grade=sdr.GetValue(2).ToString();
addressList.add(address);
        }

return addressList;
```

Comment: could you please write the webservice code and the java code?

Comment: whhich language you have used to write webService? Java Or C#

Comment: i used C#. in the address class i declare getters and setters? also i didnt get this line: Create List<Address> addressList;

Comment: can you please post the whole address class and the whole webservice method? because im new to this and tried to do it and i got alot of errors. so can you post it so i can understand please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8362958/2793134 See this post as I am not that expert in c#. It has good example exactly what you looking for .

Answer (score 0):

Declare one POJO -

```
class AllocatedData{
    String Id, name, grade;

    getters and constructor
}
```

Code -

```
List<AllocatedData> list = new ArrayList<AllocatedData>();
if (responseLevel4 != null) {
        for(int i = 0; i < responseLevel4.getPropertyCount(); i++){
            responseLevel5 = (SoapObject) responseLevel4.getProperty(i);                
            Data allocated = new AllocatedData(checkStringProperty("Id"),checkStringProperty("name"),
                    checkStringProperty("grade"));
            list.add(allocated);

        }
    } 
}
```

Which function handles if property is Null

```
public String checkStringProperty(String propertyName){
    if(responseLevel5.hasProperty(propertyName)){
        return responseLevel5.getProperty(propertyName).toString();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But my Suggestion is use JSON reponse Or generate response in JSON.
I tried it before in Asp.net web services in which difficult to generated JSON. try WCF services
Link :- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167159/How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service-in-sec

By Using json you can parse directly by GSON liabrary this is very fast as compate to SOAP.

Gson gson = new Gson();
   for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
       AllocatedData app = gson.fromJson(array.getJSONObject(i).toString(), AllocatedData .class);
       list.add(app);
   }

Comment: i want to use JSON but i dont have a complete good tutorial of how to do it, can you refer to one please?

Comment: You can refer this url. I used it before http://matijabozicevic.com/blog/android-development/android-with-wcf-service